# 5 Primary Partitions?

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

I have a compaq laptop with an ide hard drive in it. I try a lot of different OS's and I'm currently switch between Ubuntu, Windows7, and JoliOS(another linux distro). However in Win7 the partition manager reads FIVE primary partitions which I thought wasn't possible. Is this something I should be worried about?

[image: Disk Management screenshot]

---

To clarify, I have the linux partitions enclosed in a single logical partition. Screenshot of the same drive from GParted. (booting from the ubuntu partition, not liveCD if that matters)

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: Is the disk using [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record) or [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition table format? (The four-partition limit doesn't apply to GPT, but only computers using EFI can boot from it.)

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the partition manager and post it on http://imgur.com/ so we can see?

Comment: Scratch that, I looked in the hardware properties for the HDD and it is indeed MBR.

Comment: @Nick: I'm not sure about the GUI partition manager, but if you run `list disk` in command-line DISKPART, you will see a "Gpt" column. You can also boot from [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) (or any Linux CD) to manage partitions.

Comment: Screen cap:
http://imgur.com/Mv4be

Comment: @grawity I also took a screenshot of Gparted as well. http://imgur.com/cNCVJ

Comment: "5 primary partitions" is definitely a possibility.  A computer can use 5 primary partitions.  However, such a configuration is not fully supported by most operating systems, as most of them support the more common "4 primary partitions are all that are supported" standard.  Some operating systems did not follow the same standard, and can use a 5th primary partition just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if the comment on your question was a comment from Random or your deleted post but from your second screen-cap you do in fact have an extended partition **at the start of your drive** that is housing the three Linux partitions, for a total of 3 actual primary partitions.

This is corroborated by the following, though it appears that Linux is enumerating the primary partitions first even though they are located towards the end of the disk.

> Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
>   /dev/sda1 6536 28220 174183530+ 7  HPFS/NTFS
>   /dev/sda2 28221 38913 85891522+ c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
>   **/dev/sda3 1 6535 52492356 5 Extended**
>   /dev/sda5 * 1 3246 26073432 83 Linux
>   /dev/sda6 6015 6535 4184901 82 Linux swap / Solaris
>   /dev/sda7 3247 6014 22233928+ 83 Linux

Specifically note that the extended partition is at the start of the disk and encloses the Linux partitions (the second and third numbers in the columns are block start and stop numbers).

Windows does not appear to handle this case very well and while it is correctly reporting the *positions* of the partitions it is not actually showing the extended partition.

Your partition scheme is technically legal and I doubt it will cause any problems, but it is a bit unusual to say the least.

Comment: That's good to hear. I'm no stranger to windows not supporting non-standard formatting so it makes sense that it might not read logical partitions quite the same as linux. A little worried about the logical being listed first despite being at the end maybe causing HDD access delay. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Technically I believe Linux is doing it the right way, from what I remember you *are* supposed to enumerate primary partitions (the two windows partitions) before enumerating extended and logical partitions, it just looks weird to actually see it happen in practice.  I don't think it should be causing any real problems or performance drops, and it would be tricky to change it around anyway and as the phrase goes "if it isn't broke, don't fix it" :)

Answer (score 2):

The 2 other ones are probably the swap partitions created by Ubuntu and Joli OS.

If you want to be sure, give me the command line output of `sudo fdisk -l` (in Ubuntu or Joli OS).

Comment: Well, the swap partition should be shared between the both. I set up the partitions manually for the two linux installs. Could it be possible that windows is reading the logical partition as three primaries?

Comment: Also, the output of fdisk -l:
"Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            6536       28220   174183530+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2           28221       38913    85891522+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda3               1        6535    52492356    5  Extended
/dev/sda5   *           1        3246    26073432   83  Linux
/dev/sda6            6015        6535     4184901   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7            3247        6014    22233928+  83  Linux"

Comment: I see sda1 (NTFS), sda2 (FAT32), sda3 (Extended), sda5 (Linux), sda6 (Swap), and sda7 (Linux). Wich basically means that there's a partition wich Windows is installed on, an extra FAT32 partition, 2 partitions with a Linux distro on, and a shared swap partition for the Linux distro's. Do you know what the FAT32 one is? If you don't, then it may be a recovery partition from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

It is mostly a problem with windows partition manager. It shows the unrecognized(such as ext4 and swap..)) file system as primary even they are not. 
I guess it will show correctly with Ubuntu any other Linux ver. you installed, or with any other third party partition manager.

Check this also.. http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=5818