# Do I have more than 4 Primary partition on my MBR disk?

Tags: partitioning, mbr

I was trying to install Linux on the unallocated space on my disk and ran into some problems. After examining the disk, it appears that there are 5 primary partitions and a chunk of unallocated space.

In windows disk manager, they are all tagged as "Primary" (inluding the 1st 100MB "system reserved" parition), except for the "Unallocated space".

It seems to be a "basic" MBR disk, as evidenced by Properties->Volume in Windows. In fdisk, the disk type is listed as "dos" which also means MBR.

I know that MBR disks are limited to 4 primary partitions. So how is this possible?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There isn't a bug in the partition manager, you only have 4 partitions, 2 are on a extended partition

Comment: The output from Disk Management for Disk 0 is correct.   Use the command line tool `diskpart` to confirm GUI output whenever you are confused by the GUI output.

Comment: @Ramhound bug, limitation, "feature", bad design - call it as you wish. The output is misleading and problematic, or lacking information, at the very least. Can we agree on that?

Comment: With all due respect, we cannot, because I suspect the NTFS partitions were not created by Windows

Comment: Still the same bug on Windows 10. I can count 5 primary partitions on my main disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found mention of a bug in the Windows Partition Manager (sorry, the "Windows Disk Management snap-in"), so it might be that, I'll have to investigate more using another tool.

- [5 Primary Partitions?](https://superuser.com/questions/295604/5-primary-partitions#295641)
- https://neosmart.net/forums/threads/5-primary-partitions.5818/

So anyway I booted in Ubuntu and ran gparted and it does indeed seem to be "nothing  but a bug" in the Windows Disk Management tool.

[image]

Comment: Never heard of "Windows Partition Manager". The Windows Disk Management snap-in has been notoriously buggy since the Vista version. The Windows XP version shows/ed partitions correctly.

Comment: I can't give kreemoweet enough upticks on the above comment. The Windows disk partitioning GUI is a bug-fest. I strongly advise against using it for *anything,* especially on MBR disks.